# I can not find the questions I asked yesterday on this website, what's wrong?

Tags: discussion

I can not find the questions I asked yesterday on this website, what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your questions were closed (and later deleted), because they were overly broad.

Update:

Unfortunately, users cannot see their own deleted posts, unless they navigate directly to the URL of the question.  *Then,* they will appear with a gray background or some other similar treatment, depending on the site's style.

Update 2:

Some more information on the reasoning for this: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#53297)

Comment: users can't see their own deleted posts *unless they navigate to the question URL directly*, but you can as a diamond mod. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks @jeff.  I was under the impression that users could see their own deleted posts, but I may be thinking of an answer I had deleted and was probably viewing in the question itself.

Comment: As an unlogged-in user, I can see on Steven's page 5 questions (including this one), of which 4 are [closed].  I don't know if there are questions being hidden from me, of course.

Comment: @mgkrebbs Thanks for the input.  There are indeed 2 more questions which are not being shown to you.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted your questions because you were asking very poor quality questions and after closing a bunch of them, I deleted some of the more egregious ones.

Good questions are about a specific issue and are not overly broad or generic. The deleted questions were

- How to be a great investor?
- How to manage your finances?

You've asked some good questions on answer.onstartups.com but the majority of them have been closed because they just weren't the kind of questions that were good for our site.

I encourage you to keep participating but to consider that specific questions about a problem you are facing are the best types of questions.  List of books, lists of websites, tell me a story type questions just aren't very good.

Even this question on answers.onstartups.com doesn't belong:
http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/20915/does-your-business-have-a-slack-season-and-a-peak-season-on-a-yearly-basis

That particular question isn't really a bad question, it's just not suited to our sites.  How could you possibly pick one "correct" answer to that question?