# Are Questions About Careers Off-Topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

[My question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/repeat-job-advertisements-do-i-smell-a-large-turn-over-rate-closed) was closed as "Off Topic"*, but I'm confused since the FAQ on the main site doesn't list Career & Job based questions as off-topic.  I'm further perplexed since I have no access to the question I asked; I've read about the [visibility issue](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/i-can-not-find-the-questions-i-asked-yesterday-on-this-website-whats-wrong), but I still get a blank screen after I log out and navigate through the "Questions" link (I believe this is what Jeff meant when he stated that one should "navigate to the question URL directly).  Also, there are several other questions that are career based, but aren't closed.  These very questions are what I reviewed *prior* to posting to make sure that my question wouldn't fall into the cesspool of miffing inquiries.  I'm also quite dumbfounded when seeing that the "career" tag hasn't been relegated to oblivion.

So now my curiosity is piqued, but there's no way for me to really see my feedback, nor is there any way for me to edit & trim my post so as to bring it in line.  Are there any other precedents I can review (as in another closed Career question) or is there any official material readily available concerning Career questions?

Also is there any way to work around the visibility issue?  Reset my modem, checked the question from another PC, but I still can't see it; I guess I should check from the library, coffee shop, or wherever else I can find internet access?  I know I can't participate in it any longer, but I just want to *see* the feedback for future improvement.

**UPDATE**

I've had a chance to take a look at the question from another location, while being logged in.  Kind of odd that it didn't work at my place, especially since I restarted every device in the network chain; anybody else have any similar experiences?

Now that I've been able to review the comments, I'm still curious as to how it's off-topic in comparison to the other career questions?  Not asking to be abrasively smarmy, just wanting to know where the distinction lies between "Personal Finance" & one's "Career", since they're closely tied together (from my limited standpoint).  Regardless of the response I get to this meta question, I can acknowledge that my question has been ubiquitously deemed as off-topic, so I must ask: is there a domain in StackExchange where this could be appropriately migrated to?  I really do want to get some correlating responses...





*The only reason I know that it's considered "Off-Topic" is because of my Inbox; I can see small snippets of the comments made through there.

---

*Here are the full comments from the question:*

4 upvote(s): How does this relate to personal finance? – George Marian♦ 12 hours ago

1 upvote(s): @Stisfa, thanks for formatting and expressing your question well, but it's off-topic for this site, as there is no real question about personal finance or money here. – mbhunter 11 hours ago

1 upvote(s): Yes, it is a good question. I could probably write quite an essay in response. However, it is off-topic. – George Marian♦ 11 hours ago

0 upvote(s): I agree. Off Topic. (not enough rep to close) – chris 4 hours ago

Comment: You should be able to see the question just fine.  At this point, it is only closed, not deleted.  I suggest clearing the web browser's cache on the affected computer.

Comment: I'm not at home any more, but that was one of the first things I did.  In fact, I tried to access the page with 4 different browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Opera & IE.  As stated earlier, I did this with another computer I have at home, which still didn't resolve it.  I'll check again tonight.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  (I missed the fact that you checked from another PC.)  Are you firewalling anything?  (That is a total shot in the dark.)  It certainly seems like it would be caused by something on your end (whether it is something under your control or not).  If you can reproduce it and it isn't something under your control, it may warrant a bug report on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I made a mistake: I won't be home tonight.  I'm going to be out of town for tonight, so I'll have to get back with you on Thursday (busy tomorrow evening too).  Thanks for the helping hand.

Comment: @George Marian: I think I've figured it out.  I've been able to access the post on Windows XP machines, but not on any of _my_ Windows 7 machines at home.  Fortunately, I have an old Windows XP box at my place, which tested just fine.  Kind of weird; unfortunately, I haven't been able to verify that this is problematic from other Windows 7 boxes outside of my personal LAN.  Well, thanks for the link for bug reporting!

Comment: That is very odd.  I see that Jeff has already replied to your bug post on MSO, so there is no need for me to say the same here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the distinction between which career related questions are acceptable and which are not depends on their -- more or less -- direct relation to an individual's income.

Comment: A somewhat related example: we do not allow most business related questions.  The exception is generally for contractors who have incorporated, sole-proprietorships, etc.  The reasoning being that it is something that impacts an individual's income and thus related to personal finance.

Comment: So "Personal Finance and Money" is more about one's cash flow, net worth, investments (generalized), budgets, basically, anything to do with liquid & non-liquid assets (and the associated liabilities), whereas a Career is to be considered more as a meta in the scheme of this?  Would that be a correct assessment?  Apologies, as I'm trying to make this explicitly clear for myself, so as not to become a hassle to the community here.

Comment: @stisfa Yes, that seems like a reasonable (and detailed) assessment. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far George, but I'll have to overstay my welcome just a bit more ;D.  I was wondering where I could appropriately have the question migrated to?  careers.stackoverflow.com would be great, except it exists for the actual job search, not the questions associated with the act. Since it's (barely) Tech Support oriented, would it be tactful to migrate it to Server Fault?  I've checked around, and found a few tags directly oriented: career, job, job-hunting, and job-market.  There are several other variants, so I imagine Server Fault would be more conducive to the discussion?

Comment: @stisfa That is a good question.  I meant to mention earlier that I couldn't think of a good place for the question, since careers.SE isn't so much about careers and it is about jobs.  I don't know how welcome it would be on ServerFault, but I fear that it would be marginal, at best.  I'll ask around a bit and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all the help ^o^

Comment: @stisfa You're quite welcome.  That why we're here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the questions tagged "career" on money.se: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career

The questions I see there seem directly related to personal finance with the possible exception of https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/815/why-arent-programmers-paid-in-proportion-to-their-productivity.   I've since added a comment recommending that question to be closed.

Are there other questions you saw that did not relate to personal finance?